# File sink in gnuradio

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am using USRP1 along with gnuradio. I want to store received data in a file using file sink. I would like to have an idea about the flow graph and with what extension I can store the file and how to read the data from the file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit the file generated by file sink of Gnu Radio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055644/how-to-edit-the-file-generated-by-file-sink-of-gnu-radio)

Answer (score 0):

Did you search online? Pretty common task that many have documented. For example, check out [Dynamic file names in GNU Radio](http://oz9aec.net/radios/gnu-radio/dynamic-file-names-in-gnu-radio-companion), which links back to a page of examples including writing I&Q to file [2](http://oz9aec.net/radios/gnu-radio/grc-examples)